# Overflow-x: hidden and overflow-y: visible adds scrollbars

Tags: html, css

I have a table row:

```
<ul>
<li>This</li>
<li>is</li>
<li>my</li>
<li>cell</li>
</ul>
```

and some CSS:

```
UL { height: 30px; float: left }
UL LI { width: 25%; height: 100%; float: left }
```

which works great. However when I add the following CSS:

```
UL LI { overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: visible }
```

scrollbars in the cells become visible.

The default value for `overflow` is `visible` and no scrollbars are visible, yet when I change only **one** of the axis to something else, scrollbars appear.

I need the X axis to be clipped and Y axis visible (for cell text elipses and a dropdown menu).

Comment: possible duplicate of [css overflow-x visible and overflow-y hidden causes scroll bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causes-scroll-bar)

Comment: It appears to be a known "bug". Thanks "Related questions" in the sidebar for leading me to the other question!

Comment: can we have the fiddle demo of the problem so that we can identify the issue?

Comment: @SaurabhLP If you really want to you can create your own fiddle since I actually wrote out the HTML and CSS in my question from scratch. The question has already been answered and you can learn more about it through the other question linked. ;)

Comment: better for you indeed... thought it would be a good question i can resolve but a one line answer to it :), such a silly question...

Comment: @SaurabhLP If you're calling my question silly, I disagree.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem with overflow-x/y is that you cannot have visible mixed with another value so in your code `visible` will be treated as `auto`.